# PowerMockito mocked static method is calling actual class method instead of mocked class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I have a function which calls a static function in java (TimeZone.getDefault())
UnitProperty.java

```
public String getDeviceTimeZone() {
        return TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    }
```

I am trying to write unit test for this (UnitPropertyTest.java)

```
import...
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TimeZone.class)
public class UnitPropertyTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UnitProperty unitProperty;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TimeZone.class);
        unitProperty = new UnitProperty();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getDeviceTimeZone_returns_set_time_zone() throws Exception {
        String expectedTimeZone = "mock-time-zone-value";
        when(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()).thenReturn(expectedTimeZone);
        System.out.println("Mocked Time Zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        assertEquals(expectedTimeZone, unitProperty.getDeviceTimeZone());
    }
}
```

But the test fails because:

```
Mocked Time Zone: mock-time-zone-value
Expected :mock-time-zone-value
Actual   :Europe/London
```

I am not sure why `unitProperty.getDeviceTimeZone()` isn't using mocked TimeZone class but instead calling the actual TimeZone's method value?

I have been searching for a while.
Can anyone help me in understanding  this behavior?
Why isn't method in mocked class getting called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a `Supplier<TimeZone>` instead of a hard-coded static method. You won't need to mock _anything_.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-
Apologies, I didn't understand. I am very new to this. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Replace wherever you call `getDeviceTimeZone` with `private Supplier<TimeZone> tzSupplier = TimeZone::getDefault` and add a setter for it. In your test, just `unitProperty.setTzSupplier(() -> myTestValue)`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand this fully
I am trying to get the property TimeZone.getDefault().getID() 
I am not sure how a Supplier is useful here.
How will I use the Supplier to get `getID()`?

Also I don't understand what exactly is wrong with my implementation. I know that it's discouraged to mock static methods but I would still like to understand teh reason behind me getting the error on assertion